# how create 'Authentication Required' for URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, userprincipal, directory-security

For the download files from certain sites, you must ENTER your username and password in 'Authentication Required' window.
How is this implemented?

Like this picture:

[Authentication Reguired Window http://s9.uploads.im/sVCmz.png](http://s9.uploads.im/sVCmz.png)

Use 'UserPrincipal' to add 'Local User' and then use 'DirectorySecurity' to give permission, is the right way?

Comment: Place one Web.config in downloads folder and set authentication mechanism in that.

Comment: @Amit : thanks...can you please give me some examples?

Comment: Hope this helps. http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/122408-1.aspx Remeber if you want windows authenctication then specify the same and you need to handle it better by custom http handler.